# Assigning incompatible types of variables?

Tags: c, xcode5

I defined this structure

```
typedef  struct UNIAO_NOME
{
     int vert;
     struct un *Pai; 
} un;
```

but, then, when I try

```
int name (un *conj/*pointer to a subset*/)
{
    un c;/*subset*/ 
    c = *conj;
    while (c.Pai != NULL)
        c = *(c.Pai);
    return c.vert;
}
```

the editor says that

```
c = *(c.Pai);
```

is wrong, however c is of type un.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different types — inside the `struct`, you have *declared a new type `un`*. Write it like this:

```
typedef struct UNIAO_NOME
{
     int vert;
     struct UNIAO_NOME *Pai;    // refers to this type
} un;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand. You mean I should have written just "un *Pai" or "struct UNIAO_NOME *Pai"?

Answer (score 1):

You never define a `struct un` but only an identifier `un` (without `struct`) that refers to the type `struct UNIAO_NOME`.

Using `struct un*` is actually an implicit "forward declaration" of `struct un`. For the compiler this is sufficient to deduce how large a pointer to such a not-yet-defined structure will be.

An idiom that can be used for such kinds of headaches is to `typedef` all your structs *before* their full declaration:

```
typedef struct un un;
```

forward dec ^^^^^^^^^^^
type alias ------------------^^

```
struct un
{
     int vert;
     un *Pai; 
};
```

Comment: @user1286390, also, all caps identifiers are usually used for macros. This is not a rule that would be enforced by the compiler, but it hurts the eyes of most experienced C programmers.